# How did I lose 13 reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation

A few minutes ago I was on the site with 1,192 reputation points. I just came back and I lost 13 points already!! How could this happen?

I didn't downvote 13 answers, and I don't see anyone has downvoted me.

Comment: 'Ah got 'dem disappearin' rep points blues ;(

Comment: When in doubt check the "show deleted posts" box.  Or just run a full reputation report by visiting http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You posted an answer to a question. That answer was accepted (+15), but had a downvote (-2), giving you a total reputation gain of +13.

The question was deleted 51 minutes ago by 3 members of the community, taking your answer, and the reputation you had gained from it, with it.

---

The post in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970188/how-to-print-a-2d-array-whose-length-of-each-row-is-diiferent/35970353#35970353